# after animated timing finish, go to home page

Tags: react-native

When an animated timing finishes, I want to go Login page but I don't know 
how to do that. Can someone help me?

And also can someone give me an example about saving username and password
when enter your username and password to login page?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Navigator } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './Login';


export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state={
        fadeAmin: new Animated.Value(1),

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        () => {
          Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
            this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
            {
              toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
              duration: 5000,

                  // 2000ms
            }
          ).start();
        })              // Starts the animation
    }

    render() {
      let { fadeAnim } = this.state;


        return (
          <View style = {{flex:1, alignItems:"center", justifyContent:'center'}}>

            <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
            {this.props.children}

              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../../image/maxresdefault.jpg')} />           

            </Animated.View>

            {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.fadeOut} >
              <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', marginTop: 10 }}>
              fade out
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> */}

          </View>

        );      
    }
  }
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
      resizeMode:'cover',
      flex:1
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// All you need is to pass a callback to start() like this;

Animated.timing(    
            this.state.fadeAnim,
            {
              toValue: 0,        
              duration: 5000,
            }
          ).start(
            ()=>{} // this is your callback which will trigger after animation ends.
                 );
        })
```